# Emails in cloud with Google Apps combined with Exchange server 2007?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, g-suite

is it possible, or viable, to use Google Apps in combination with our server running Exchange 2007?

This being as we would like to keep emails securely in the cloud with Google Apps, but have the superior calendar/contact management of exchange.

What would be the best way to set this up? Let the emails arrive to Google and then have our exchange server fetch them using IMAP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can access google apps with imap. Alternatively, you can have your Exchange infrastructure sync directly (and live) with google apps so that you have calendaring on both platforms.

You can also leave some users entirely on exchange, while having others entirely within google apps. Calendar sync will work between them all.